# multirow doesn't skip cell

Tags: tables, tabularx, multirow

I am trying to use a simple table with multirows. My MWE is the following

```
\documentclass[twocolumn,epjc3]{svjour3} 

\usepackage{makecell}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\newcommand{\Ufour}{$^{234}$U}
\newcommand{\Ufive}{$^{235}$U}
\newcommand{\Ueight}{$^{238}$U}

\begin{document}

\begin{table*}[t]
\centering
% table caption is above the table
\caption{Summary table of the calculated correction factor values and the neutron fluxes along with the corresponding uncertainties.}
\label{tab:summary_of_factors}% Give a unique label
% For LaTeX tables use
\begin{tabular}{c|c|ccc}
\hline\noalign{\smallskip}
Sample & \makecell{Neutron Energy \\ (MeV)} & $f_\text{par}$ &  $f_\text{Out/In}$ &\makecell{Neutron Flux \\ ($10^4$ neutrons/cm$^2$s)} \\
\noalign{\smallskip}\hline
\multirow{3}{*}{\Ufive}  & $0.452(8)$ & $0.81(12)$ & - & $1.82(6)$ \\
$0.550(8)$ & $0.60(8)$ & - & $1.75(6)$ \\
$0.651(8)$ & $0.77(9)$ & - & $4.42(18)$ \\
\hline
\multirow{3}{*}{\Ueight} & $7.5(1)$ & $0.036(7)$ & $0.081(8)$ & $3.39(17)$ \\
$8.7(1)$ & $0.059(9)$ & $0.120(7)$ & $5.10(17)$ \\
$10.0(1)$ & $0.18(1)$ & $0.111(5)$ & $13.4(5)$ \\
\hline
\multirow{6}{*}{\Ufour}  & $0.452(8)$ & $0.152(3)$ & - & $2.85(10)$ \\
$0.550(8)$ & $0.133(2)$ & - & $2.66(9)$ \\
$0.651(8)$ & $0.0.213(1)$ & - & $6.93(28)$ \\
%\hline
$7.5(1)$ & $0.029(6)$ & $0.073(4)$ & $14.4(3)$ \\
$8.7(1)$ & $0.063(7)$ & $0.117(1)$ & $19.4(3)$ \\
$10.0(1)$ & $0.242(9)$ & $0.113(3)$ & $40.4(6)$ \\
\end{tabular}
\end{table*}

\end{document}
```

The problem is that although the cell in which multirow is called should contain only what is in the 3rd argument , in fact it is somehow completely ignored as seen on the figure

[image]

Any idea on what might be the issue?

Comment: I'd say you are missing a `&' in front of lines 
$0.550(8)$ & $0.60(8)$ & - & $1.75(6)$ \\
and $0.651(8)$ & $0.77(9)$ & - & $4.42(18)$ \\ 
in the rows you want to combine. ... Add a & in front of each line below the multirows

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Manually adding vertical spaces via `\noalign{\smallskip}` is not a good idea. Just use `booktabs` and it will automatically make your table nicer. No need for any vertical pipes `|` in this case. You can even go another step forward and use the `S` column type from `siunitx` package to align numbers at the decimal point `.` and to make some other enhancements.

```
\documentclass[twocolumn,epjc3]{svjour3} 

\usepackage{makecell,booktabs}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\newcommand{\Ufour}{$^{234}$U}
\newcommand{\Ufive}{$^{235}$U}
\newcommand{\Ueight}{$^{238}$U}


\begin{document}

\begin{table*}[t]
\centering
% table caption is above the table
\caption{Summary table of the calculated correction factor values and the neutron fluxes along with the corresponding uncertainties.}
\label{tab:summary_of_factors}% Give a unique label
% For LaTeX tables use
\begin{tabular}{@{}lcccc@{}} \toprule
%\noalign{\smallskip}
Sample & \makecell{Neutron Energy \\ (MeV)} & $f_\text{par}$ &  $f_\text{Out/In}$ &\makecell{Neutron Flux \\ ($10^4$ neutrons/cm$^2$s)} \\ \midrule
%\noalign{\smallskip}
\multirow{3}{*}{\Ufive}  & $0.452(8)$ & $0.81(12)$ & - & $1.82(6)$ \\
& $0.550(8)$ & $0.60(8)$ & - & $1.75(6)$ \\
& $0.651(8)$ & $0.77(9)$ & - & $4.42(18)$ \\ \midrule
\multirow{3}{*}{\Ueight} & $7.5(1)$ & $0.036(7)$ & $0.081(8)$ & $3.39(17)$ \\
& $8.7(1)$  & $0.059(9)$ & $0.120(7)$ & $5.10(17)$ \\
& $10.0(1)$ & $0.18(1)$  & $0.111(5)$ & $13.4(5)$ \\ \midrule
\multirow{6}{*}{\Ufour}  & $0.452(8)$ & $0.152(3)$ & - & $2.85(10)$ \\
& $0.550(8)$ & $0.133(2)$ & - & $2.66(9)$ \\
& $0.651(8)$ & $0.0.213(1)$ & - & $6.93(28)$ \\
%\hline
& $7.5(1)$  & $0.029(6)$ & $0.073(4)$ & $14.4(3)$ \\
& $8.7(1)$  & $0.063(7)$ & $0.117(1)$ & $19.4(3)$ \\
& $10.0(1)$ & $0.242(9)$ & $0.113(3)$ & $40.4(6)$ \\ \bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{table*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

This should work:

```
\documentclass{article} 

\usepackage{makecell}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\newcommand{\Ufour}{$^{234}$U}
\newcommand{\Ufive}{$^{235}$U}
\newcommand{\Ueight}{$^{238}$U}


\begin{document}

\begin{table*}[t]
\centering
% table caption is above the table
\caption{Summary table of the calculated correction factor values and the neutron fluxes along with the corresponding uncertainties.}
\label{tab:summary_of_factors}% Give a unique label
% For LaTeX tables use
\begin{tabular}{c|c|ccc}
\hline\noalign{\smallskip}
Sample & \makecell{Neutron Energy \\ (MeV)} & $f_\text{par}$ &  $f_\text{Out/In}$ &\makecell{Neutron Flux \\ ($10^4$ neutrons/cm$^2$s)} \\
\noalign{\smallskip}\hline
\multirow{3}{*}{\Ufive}  & $0.452(8)$ & $0.81(12)$ & - & $1.82(6)$ \\
& $0.550(8)$ & $0.60(8)$ & - & $1.75(6)$ \\
& $0.651(8)$ & $0.77(9)$ & - & $4.42(18)$ \\
\hline
\multirow{3}{*}{\Ueight} & $7.5(1)$ & $0.036(7)$ & $0.081(8)$ & $3.39(17)$ \\
& $8.7(1)$ & $0.059(9)$ & $0.120(7)$ & $5.10(17)$ \\
& $10.0(1)$ & $0.18(1)$ & $0.111(5)$ & $13.4(5)$ \\
\hline
\multirow{6}{*}{\Ufour}  & $0.452(8)$ & $0.152(3)$ & - & $2.85(10)$ \\
& $0.550(8)$ & $0.133(2)$ & - & $2.66(9)$ \\
& $0.651(8)$ & $0.0.213(1)$ & - & $6.93(28)$ \\
%\hline
& $7.5(1)$ & $0.029(6)$ & $0.073(4)$ & $14.4(3)$ \\
& $8.7(1)$ & $0.063(7)$ & $0.117(1)$ & $19.4(3)$ \\
& $10.0(1)$ & $0.242(9)$ & $0.113(3)$ & $40.4(6)$ \\
\end{tabular}
\end{table*}

\end{document}
```

producing this:

[image]